# Is there a Java Charset implementation for IBM420_rtl?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm using the ICU4j charset detector, which for some input binary has returned "IBM420_rtl" as the detected charset.

I have the ICU4j charsets jar on the classpath as well, but even it does not hold an implementation for that charset.

Is there a library out there which has a Charset implementation for this one? It's very interesting how ICU4j would spit out a charset which it knows it can't decode itself, even though it can detect it...

Answer (score -1):

Try [the java library IBM created](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/) to support it, downloadable [here](http://site.icu-project.org/download).

p.s. I just googled "ICU4j java" and it was the first hit

Comment: Congratulations, you have successfully found the library I already said I was using when I stated my question.

Comment: You didn't say you were using it. You only said you detected that your input was of that type. Try using the library to decode your input.

Comment: I said, "I'm using the ICU4j charset detector", and I also said "I have the ICU4j charsets jar on the classpath". I don't think it could be any more clear than that. I think you just skimmed the question.